# How to use Watch APIs in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

How to implement watch API using OkHttp and Retrofit in Java. Do I have to use WebSockets for this to implement?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already done so, running `kubectl --v=100 get -w events` will show you the equivalent pseudo-`curl` command that kubectl is invoking on your behalf

But if the behavior of `kubectl logs` is any indicator, yes, I would expect websockets are likely involved